# How to enable reveal highlighting in `GridView`

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp-xaml, fluent-design

I am developing a UWP app with the target build and min build of 16299. According to the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal#controls-that-automatically-use-reveal) `GridView` should have the reveal highlight automatically for the FCU. But I could not see anything. `AutoSuggestBox` is also not working. However, `NavigationView` is showing the reveal highlight effects.

Below is the XAML. The project is developed using Windows Template Studio 1.5 in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.2.

```xaml
<GridView Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Content="1" Width="150" Height="200"  />
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Content="1" Width="150" Height="200" />
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Content="1" Width="150" Height="200" />
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="1">
        <Button Content="1" Width="150" Height="200" />
    </Border>
</GridView>
```

Comment: It seems that FCU does not support it yet. I have tried the code on Redstone 4 and it works as expected. The way out may be to copy the styles from Redstone 4 SDK.

Comment: I have tested it within dark theme, it works in my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I could not see anything. AutoSuggestBox is also not working. However, NavigationView is showing the reveal highlight effects.

`GridView` automatically use [`Reveal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal#controls-that-automatically-use-reveal). The problem is that reveal highlighting has been covered by UWP default light theme.

You could modify the page `RequestedTheme` to dark, you will see the reveal highlighting.

```
<Page    
      ......  
   RequestedTheme="Dark >
</Page>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works with the dark theme. However, the effects are not that impressive, compared to what you can experience in the latest preview build 17063. I am not sure if I can just use the latest generic.xaml to get that effect.

Comment: Yep, To be sure `GridView` automatically use Reveal.